# using docker stack deploy on oracle linux 6

Tags: linux, oracle, docker

i am using oracle linux 6 with version

```
Docker version 1.12.6, build 1512168
```

the oracle linux version is:

```
Linux slc10hbw 4.1.12-61.1.28.el6uek.x86_64
```

running

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack
```

results into:

```
docker: 'stack' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'.
```

How to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker [`stack`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack/) was added in v1.13.

It doesn't look like Oracle [have a 1.13 package yet](http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/addons/x86_64/) so you would need a [Docker EE subscription to get a build directly  from Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/oracle/)